# how do I html5?

Tags: html

I've been reading through stuff on html5 but have a very basic question: what do I need for html5? Do I need to download anything (from where?)?

I have LAMP...does HTML5 support mysql databases?

Comment: I'm not saying this is a troll, but if I was going to troll, I think it would look like this.

Comment: I suggest you look into learning the high level basics of web technologies.  This question doesn't make much sense as it stands.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you ever use HTML4? :)

Comment: FYI: I would advice you to hold on this, <a href="http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/w3c-hold-html5-in-websites-041">W3C Stated not to use HTML5 yet!</a>, because of interoperatibility

Comment: @BalusC he probably downloaded it off torrents to avoid the really expensive licensing fees... Oh wait... =)

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you know how to shot web?

Comment: @BoltClock that is my new favourite emoticon!

Comment: @Alex: How did you find your way here? :)

Comment: @BoltClock I sometimes look through the questions with a lot of down votes. Some of them are *highly* entertaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing - you just do what you always do with any HTML files. HTML5 only works in browsers that support new HTML5 tags. Those that don't support new tags will be rendered as just another inline tag.

mySQL doesn't care about what HTML you use. You need to use PHP or programming language to interface with DB to output to a HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>Test page</title>

    <article>An article</article>
</html>
```

Also you might want to check out html5 boilerplate
http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: technically speaking you don't need the html tag - it's optional :) - see section titled "HTML5 Minified" - http://html5doctor.com/your-questions-answered-11/

Comment: Is this a div in my html fives? That should clearly be a section! ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 requires [nothing special](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) from web servers.